# Add subfield set with a bit map to ISO 8583 message using JPOS

Tags: iso8583, jpos

I am new to JPOS. I want to add a set of sub fields into a single field with a bitmap. I tried with following URL but I didn't get any good result.

[PISO 8583 subfield using JPOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737216/piso-8583-subfield-using-jpos)

What I want to do :

I have to send a "0100" request. In this case I want to put CVV value into "126.10" field. Field "126" has many sub fields and field "126" has a bit map.

Is it possible to do this kind of case using JPOS? If it is possible how can we do that. If you have any sample please help me to complete this task.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tired from that url and why didn't you get any good result?, What did you try and what happened when you tried? Please edit your question and give those details so we can help. Here you have another example wide tested since is part of the jpos distribution. https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/dist/cfg/packager/postpack.xml

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the reply. Finally I solved the problem using your URL.

Answer (score 0):

With jPos it is possible to configure an isofieldpackager in the packager XML file as shown in the example below. The "emitBitmap" property determines if field 56 will have a bitmap.

Sample packager MXL file with SubFieldPackager in field 56:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC
        "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN"
        "http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd">

<isopackager>
    <isofield id="0" length="4" name="MESSAGE TYPE INDICATOR" pad="true" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC" />
    <isofield id="1" length="8" name="BIT MAP" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BITMAP" />
    <isofield id="2" length="99" name="?" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLNUM" />
    <isofield id="3" length="6" name="PROCESSING CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC" />
    <isofield id="11" length="6" name="?" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC" />
    <isofield id="12" length="6" name="?" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC" />
    <isofield id="13" length="4" name="?" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC" />
    <isofield id="14" length="4" name="?" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC" />
    <isofield id="24" length="3" name="?" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC" />
    <isofield id="39" length="2" name="?" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" />
    <isofield id="41" length="8" name="?" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" />
    <isofield id="42" length="999" name="?" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLBINARY" />
    <isofieldpackager id="56" length="999" name="ADDITIONAL TRANSACTION DATA" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLBINARY"
        packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericSubFieldPackager" emitBitmap="true">
        <isofield id="1" length="2" name="PHONE PREFIX" pad="true" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC" />
        <isofield id="2" length="9" name="PHONE" pad="true" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC" />
        <isofield id="3" length="99" name="?" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLBINARY" />
    </isofieldpackager>
    <isofield id="61" length="999" name="SERVER INFORMATIONS" class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLCHAR" />
</isopackager>
```

The projects of this file can be found in the repositories of the links below. They are simple projects that send and respond ISO 8583 messages.

Repositories of ISO 8583 projects:
https://github.com/alexlirio/iso-sender
https://github.com/alexlirio/iso-responder

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to include the bitmap field like this.

```
        <isofield 
            id="0" 
            length="8" 
            name="BIT MAP" 
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BITMAP" />
```

Also set this two attributes on the isofieldpackager tag.

```
        emitBitmap="true"
        bitmapField="0"
```

```
<isofieldpackager 
        id="56" 
        length="999"
        name="ADDITIONAL TRANSACTION DATA" 
        class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLNUM"
        packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericSubFieldPackager"
        emitBitmap="true"
        bitmapField="0">
        <isofield 
            id="0" 
            length="8" 
            name="BIT MAP" 
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BITMAP" />
        <isofield 
            id="1" 
            length="2" 
            name="???" 
            pad="true"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" />
        <isofield 
            id="2" 
            length="9" 
            name="???" 
            pad="true"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" />
        <isofield 
            id="3" 
            length="99" 
            name="???"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC" />
    </isofieldpackager>
```